# Express + Passport : How to destroy session by user info used in serialization?

Tags: session, express, passport.js

I've implemented passport authentication in an express application. And serialization is done on the `username`.

**Passport:**

```
passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy(verifyCredentials));

function verifyCredentials(username, password, done){
    //Check from the cached data
    if(user has already logged in){
        //Destroy session corresponding to `username'
    } 
    else {
        //Verify the credentials
        if(verified){
            //Cached username here
            done(null, user.username);
        } else {
            done(404, null)
        } 
    }
}

passport.serializeUser(function(username, done){
    done(null, username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    done(null, {username:username})
});
```

**Routes**

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        isAuthenticated : req.isAuthenticated(),
        user : {name : req.body.username}
    });
});
```

**Scenario:**

1. A user logs in from a tab - we get the session created
2. User does a `GET /login` in a new tab and logs in using the same credentials again

**Requirement:**

- User is prompted that the user is already logged in and given an option to invalidate the previous session
- If user chooses to invalidate, destroy the session corresponding to `username'

After the prompt, how do I go about invalidation?

Any help is appreciated. Much thanks!